# Mudar texto Previous e Next nos links de paginação

Tags: php, html, wordpress, paginação

Eu defini no functions.php os parâmetros da paginação e dei um echo onde eu quero que os links apareçam, até aí tudo bem.

O problema é que os textos de previous e next não estão modificando. Coloquei um texto nada a ver e vejam o que aparece. Estão até traduzidos...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<?php $args = array(
    'base'               => '%_%',
    'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
    'total'              => 1,
    'current'            => 0,
    'show_all'           => false,
    'end_size'           => 1,
    'mid_size'           => 2,
    'prev_next'          => true,
    'prev_text'          => __('wefdwqd'),
    'next_text'          => __('wqdwqdqw'),
    'type'               => 'list',
    'add_args'           => false,
    'add_fragment'       => '',
    'before_page_number' => '',
    'after_page_number'  => ''
); ?>



<!-- Links de paginação -->
<?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: As imagens é o que você quer? Está com o Opache ativo?

Comment: Não, o texto da imagem é o que aparece, o que eu eu quero é poder modificar o texto pra qualquer coisa. O array deveria fazer isso, mas não está.